# Radconfirm with no title bar and close button

Tags: telerik

How to have telerik radconfirm  with no title bar and the confirm template

Answer (score 1):

The RadWindowManager has a VisibleTitlebar property.

You could also take a look at the RadNotification control, that may suit your needs better.

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/notification/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx